# Lenevo G580 Model 20157 can't open bios menu

Tags: boot, uefi

I am facing problem in opening the bios menu by pressing the system rescue botton which bring up the CMOS menu under which there is bios menu where I can change the UEFI/Legecy mode or change the boot order but the menu won't work. The Laptop won't recognize the Windows 8.1 or 7 or any Lunix except two one of which is Lunix mint and another ubantu 14.4, another usb which I created along with these two was windows 8 the laptop wont even recognise the usb as bootable. where the same is working fine for another mini laptop I own or even on another PC. 
I have updated the bios yes but did not keep the old bios backup. the new bios was working fine untill recnetly. Now is there any way I could revert the bios to old version or open it up and change the bios settng somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8, you should enable [advanced startup](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-access-the-bios-on-a-windows-8-computer/), which might help you accessing your BIOS again.